# Given an array of ints and a number n, calculate the number of ways to sum to n using the ints

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I saw this problem in my interview preparation.

> Given an array of ints and a number n, calculate the number of ways to
>   sum to n using the ints

Following code is my solution. I tried to solve this by recursion. Subproblem is for each int in the array, we can either pick it or not.

```
public static int count(List<Integer> list, int n) {
    System.out.print(list.size() + ", " + n);
    System.out.println();
    if (n < 0 || list.size() == 0)
      return 0;
    if (list.get(0) == n)
      return 1;
    int e = list.remove(0);
    return count(list, n) + count(list, n - e);
  }
```

I tried to use [10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5] for ints, and set n to 8. The result should be 4. However, I got 0. I tried to print what I have on each layer of stack to debug as showed in the code. Following is what I have:

```
7, 8
6, 8
5, 8
4, 8
3, 8
2, 8
1, 8
0, 8
0, 3
0, 7
0, 2
0, 1
0, 6
0, 7
0, -2
```

This result confuses me. I think it looks right from beginning to (0, 3). Starting from (0, 7), it looks wrong to me. I expect (1, 7) there. Because if I understand correctly, this is for count(list, n - e) call on second to the bottom layer on the stack. The list operation on the lower layer shouldn't impact the list on the current layer.
So my questions are:

1. why is it (0, 7) instead of (1, 7) based on my current code?
2. what adjustment should I do to my current code to get the correct result?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate: *that* poster asked how to solve the problem; @Fei Qu has chosen and implemented a solution, but needs debugging help.  Yes, a careful comparison of solutions might show the algorithmic difference, but I think it's reasonable to let this question stand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why your algorithm is not working is because you are using one list that is being modified before the recursive calls.

Since the list is *passed by reference*, what ends up happening is that you recursively call `remove` until there is nothing in the list any more and then all of your recursive calls are going to return `0`

What you could do is create two copies of the list on every recursive step. However, this would be way too inefficient.

A better way would be to use an index `i` that marks the element in the list that is being looked at during the call:

```
public static int count(List<Integer> list, int n, int i) {
    //System.out.print(list.size() + ", " + n);
    //System.out.println();
    if (n < 0 || i <= 0)
      return 0;

    int e = list.get(i);  // e is the i-th element in the list
    if (e == n)
      return 1 + count(list, n, i-1);   // Return 1 + check for more possibilities without picking e

    return count(list, n, i-1) + count(list, n - e, i-1);   // Result if e is not picked + result if e is picked
}
```

You would then pass `yourList.size() - 1` for `i` on the initial function call.

One more point is that when you `return 1`, you still have to add the number of possibilities for when your element `e` is not *picked* to be part of a sum. Otherwise, if - for example - your last element in the list was `n`, the recursion would end on the first step only returning `1` and not checking for more possible number combinations.

Finally, you might want to rewrite the algorithm using a dynamic approach, since that would give you a **way better** running time.